# How to prove convergence in p given convergence a.s. for a subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $(X_{n})$ which is Cauchy in Probability sense i.e. $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_{\epsilon}$ s.t.
$P\{|X_n - X_m|>\epsilon \}<\epsilon$ $\forall n,m>N_\epsilon$. In the first part to a question, I proved $\exists$ a subsequence and a random variable $X$ s.t. $X_{{n}_{k}}\rightarrow X$ a.s. using BC lemma.

But I am having trouble showing $X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability? My intuition says if for every subsequence of $X_n$ there is a further subsequence which converges to $X$, then I can make a case for $X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability. But in the previous case, I proved existence of a particular subsequence and am not sure how to make a connection to every subsequence. Any hints are appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Firstly you can show that there is a subsequence $X_{n_i}$ such that $P(|X_{n_i}-X_{n_j}|>\frac{1}{2^i})<\frac1{2^i}$ for any $j\ge i$. Using this then you can show that the subsequence $X_{n_i}$ converges to some r.v. X, a.s. Then you can try to prove that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in Probability.

Comment: Yes, I've already proved the first part, as you say, using $P\{|X_{n_{k+1}}-X_{n_k}|>2^{-k}\}<2^{-k}$. Having trouble with the conv in probability part.

Comment: Note that $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\le P(|X_n-X_{n_i}|>\epsilon/2)+P(|X_{n_i}-X|>\epsilon/2)$.

Comment: It comes from the following event relationship: $[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]\subset[|X_n-X_{n_i}|>\epsilon/2]\cup[|X_{n_i}-X|>\epsilon/2]$.

Comment: That's neat. I see your argument that the right hand side terms go to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ but I don't know why. First term goes to $0$ because the sequence is Cauchy and the second term goes to $0$ because $X_{n_i}\rightarrow X$ a.s.? Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yep, the second term goes to 0 since "a.s convergence implies convergence in $P$".

Comment: Perfect, that's what I thought, you are the best :)

Comment: Also, for the first part, I have a question about the subsequence, I just claimed there is a subsequence s.t. $P\{|X_{n_i}-X_{n_j}|>2^{-i}\} < 2^{-i} \forall j>i$. But can I construct the index $i$ explicitly so that the above condition holds? Like $n_i = 2^i$ maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you can't, because Cauchy in $P$ gives us nothing but the existence. Maybe $n_i=2^{2^i}$ or vastly larger. We can require the rate of  growth of $n_i$ is "faster" than any rate we want, e.g., we can require $n_i\ge i^2$ or $n_i\ge 2^i$, but we can't expect that the rate of growth of $n_i$ is "slower" than any given rate.

Comment: That's true, makes sense! Thanks again.